# Use PHP to change background image from user input

Tags: php, html, css

Started working in PHP for the first time this past week.  I'm trying to make the background image change depending on the user input from a form.  Here is the PHP code:

```
if ($gender == 'Male') 
            echo '<body style="background-color: red">';
if ($gender == 'Female') 
            echo '<body style="background-image: url("../images/female.jpg")">';
```

I am able to change the background color based on selection, but when I try to change it to an image nothing happens.  Image is in the correct path. Not sure if it can even be done this way.  I know there are probably other ways to do it, but probably not on my php coding level (just a beginner).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a page we can take a look at what's being output? Also, just out of curiosity, can you try changing it to `'<body style="background-image: url(../images/female.jpg)">'` (Removed the quotations surrounding the url path)

Comment: What's the generated output (HTML) for `$gender == 'Female'`?

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  That had to be the only thing I didn't try.  It worked with:  '<body style="background-image: url(../images/female.jpg)">'

Comment: As a side note, it would be cleaner to set a CSS class on the `<body>` tag rather than explicitly writing the whole style and tag out for each condition.

Comment: @hungerstar I guess I wouldn't know how to do that...yet.  So, if I give the body a class how would it set the different images depending on the user selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without setting CSS class:

```
if ($gender == 'Male')
    echo '<body style="background-color: red">';
if ($gender == 'Female')
    echo '<body style="background-image: url(../images/female.jpg)">';
```

But it will be good to define CSS class as said @hungerstar

your css file:

```
.male {
    background-color: red
}

.female {
    background-image: url(../images/female.jpg)
}
```

and your php code with css classes:

```
if ($gender == 'Male')
    echo '<body class="male"';
if ($gender == 'Female')
    echo '<body class="female">';
```

Comment: I would use a `<body class="' . $body_class . '">` approach myself to reduce duplication of markup in the source.

Answer (score 0):

try this, generate class in your css ;)

```
if ($gender == 'Male'){
    echo '<body class="bg-male">';
}elseif ($gender == 'Female') {
    echo '<body class="bg-female">';
}else{
    echo '<body class="default">';
}
```